# Strange spacing

Tags: spacing

This MWE

```
% Typeset with pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.4)
% (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.4.30)  21 JUN 2023 06:48

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\hbox to 5cm{This (what?) looks ugly}

\end{document}
```

gives the following output:
[image]

It the spacing supposed to be correct?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Justified text in a fixed-width box is going to look ugly most of the time.

Comment: It occurred to me in a "real situation" in a paragraph. A good linebreak was not possible, therefore the line was stretched. And I wondered whether the space after the closing brace really should be larger than the other spaces.  But I agree that space after a sentence end (indicated by a period, a question or exclamation mark) should be larger than an intraword space. But the space between "(what?)" and "looks" is an intraword space and not a space after the end of a sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Your `\hbox to 5cm` (which should be `\makebox[5cm][s]`) just aggravates the problem of `\nonfrenchspacing`, which is the default in LaTeX.

Consider the simpler example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

This. Looks ugly.

This (what?) looks ugly

\setlength{\xspaceskip}{1cm plus 0.5cm minus 0.2cm}

This. Looks ugly.

This (what?) looks ugly

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you look closely, you'll see that in the first line the space between `.` and `L` is wider than the space between `s` and `u`. Similarly, the space in the second line between `)` and `l` is wider than the normal interword space between `s` and `u`.

The same is emphasized in the following lines, where the `\xspaceskip` is set to a (really too) large value, by way of examples.

After “strong punctuation”, TeX will insert wider interword space, in order to comply with a (not really standard) habit of American typography. My opinion on the matter is that Knuth likes it. Many don't (including myself).

The parenthesis is “transparent” as far as the rules for interword space are concerned, so the space following `)` is treated just like it followed `?`.

Solution: declare `\frenchspacing` and forget about the matter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

This. Looks ugly.

This (what?) looks ugly

\setlength{\xspaceskip}{1cm plus 0.5cm minus 0.2cm}

This. Looks ugly.

This (what?) looks ugly

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `\frenchspacing` is a misnomer, because the rules for punctuation in French typography are completely different.

Comment: Ok. I used the `\hbox to 5cm` just to simulate the effect.

Answer (score 3):

The `?` character has a spacefactor of 3000. That means that the subsequent space (ignoring characters with a space factor of 0 such as `)`) has `3000 / 1000 = 3` times the stretch and `1000 / 3000 = 1/3` times the shrink. If you want an ordinary word space, then you need to reset the spacefactor back to 1000. LaTeX has the control sequence `\@` which does this. So try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\hbox to 5cm{This (what?)\@ looks ugly}

This (what?)\@ looks ugly

\end{document}
```

Here is what the output looks like with the corrected spacefactor:

[image]

Comment: that would result with `Underfull \hbox (badness 3612) detected`

Comment: That's just the result of trying to justify too little text into too wide of a box.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I looked for.  The TeX heuristics to enlarge the spacefactor for the first space after a quotation mark confused me. It is clearly wrong in the case at hand.